ConfigureTestServices executes in unexpected order
Summary
I'm expecting the bodies of various ConfigureTestServices calls to be executed in the order in which they are queued up. But the first one is executing last.
Details
1 - GetHostBuilder()
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseEnvironment("test")
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureTestServices(services => {
        var service = Substitute.For<IService>();
        service.Id = "Foo";
        services.replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IService), service));
    });

return builder;

2 - Use the builder
var builder = GetHostBuilder();
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => {
    var service = Substitute.For<IService>();
    service.Id = "Bar";
    services.replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IService), service));
});

using var server = new TestServer(builder);

// server.Services.GetRequiredService<IService>().Id ==> "Foo"

When I debug the test, I can see the replacement code from #2 executing, then later the code from #1.
Why doesn't #1 execute first, given that #2 is called on the instance obtained from #1?
This feels like the same as simply chaining the calls to ConfigureTestServices in order, where I would expect #1 to execute prior to #2, as well. What am I missing?
